# replace login fragment by home fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am novice in programming android j would like to work with fragments but we want to replace the fragment login by the fragment home when we click on connection j can not get any idea

I have to try a lot of technique but I can not get what I want

here is what i have as a code.
Class MainActivity :

```
package com.cuveri.mobile.vue;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.*;
import com.cuveri.mobile.controleur.LoginFragment;
import com.example.symameri.mhis.R;
import static com.example.symameri.mhis.R.layout.activity_Main;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_Main);
    LoginFragment fragment = (LoginFragment) getFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.logFragment);






}





/* public void navigatetoHomeActivity(){
    Intent homeIntent = new 
Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
    finish();
}*/

}
```

Layout actuvity_Main:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height = "match_parent" android:paddingLeft= 
"@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
android:paddingRight="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
android:paddingTop="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
android:paddingBottom = "@android:dimen/app_icon_size" tools:context = 
"com.cuveri.mobile.vue.MainActivity"
android:background="#e2dfdf">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/logFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.cuveri.mobile.controleur.LoginFragment"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/hFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.cuveri.mobile.controleur.HomeFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Class Login_Fragment

```
package com.cuveri.mobile.controleur;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.*;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cuveri.mobile.vue.MainActivity;
import com.example.symameri.mhis.R;

import java.io.IOException;

import ca.mimic.oauth2library.OAuth2Client;
import ca.mimic.oauth2library.OAuthError;
import ca.mimic.oauth2library.OAuthResponse;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{
//code le comportement du login
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
TextView errorMsg;
EditText identify;
EditText password;
Button connexion;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    errorMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    password =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Mot_de_passe);
    identify=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Identifiant);
    connexion =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_connexion) ;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    }
    public void loginUser (View view) {
    String username = identify.getText().toString();
    String passwords = password.getText().toString();


    OAuth2Client client = new OAuth2Client.Builder("macuverie_mobile", 
"appmobile", "http://10.0.2.2:8080/oauth/token")

.grantType("password").username(username).password(passwords).build();

    OAuthResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.requestAccessToken();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), e.getMessage(), 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    String accessToken = "";
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        accessToken = response.getAccessToken();
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "acces_token" + 
 accessToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       new MainActivity().navigatetoHomeActivity();
        //String refreshToken = response.getRefreshToken();
    } else {
        OAuthError error = response.getOAuthError();
        String errorMsg = error.getError();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


  }


  }
```

Class Home_Fragment :

```
package com.cuveri.mobile.controleur;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import com.example.symameri.mhis.R;

 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
}
}
```

Comment: you need to use `Framelayout` and transaction manager, hit the official docs

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this problem is to replace the Fragment widget with FrameLayout, and you need to use this last widget as a container.

After that, you can use the FragmentTransation to add, replace or delete a fragment at the runtime.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Answer (score 0):

There is too many options for that but you must not use any of that.

Because of ["Separate of Concern Principle"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98765/9651407) or ["Single-responsibility Principle"](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).

Let me explain: Login and Home fragments belongs different business logic. So both must have separate activities. After that If you do not want to reuse some parts of theese activities, then you actually do not need to fragments neither.